# What's the expected number of locations with exactly one phone number in a hash table?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expectation

From Harvard Stat 110

> A hash table is being used to store the phone numbers of k people, storing each
>   person's phone number in a uniformly random location, represented by an integer between 1 and n (see Exercise 25 from Chapter 1 for a description of hash tables). Find the expected number of locations with no phone numbers stored, the expected number with exactly one phone number, and the expected number with more than one phone number (should these quantities add up to n?).

Would someone, please, give me a reasoned solution for the expected number with exactly one phone number?

My argument is: Let $I_j$ be an i.r.v. for the $j^{th}$ location having exactly $1$ phone number. If we treat the $k$ phone numbers as a vector, each entry in the vector will have $n$ choices of locations. Now we choose one of the $k$ entries and send it into the $j^{th}$ location. Each one of the other $k-1$ entries have $n-1$ locations to choose from. Then, $P(I_j=1)=k((n-1)/n)^{k-1}$. Then we multiply by $n$ to get the expected value. But this is different from the book's answer.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Done :)

Comment: Suppose the first and second location each have precisely one entry.  Haven't you counted that twice?

Comment: @saulspatz Maybe but I can't imagine it. Aren't the indicator random variables independent from each other? Shouldn't we look at the $j^{th}$ location only?

Comment: @saulspatz Why did you delete your answer? I couldn't catch up to read all of it...

Comment: @AbduMagdy Because your approach is much better than mine.  Look at my revised answer.

Comment: Your edits turned your about-to-be-downvoted question into a very informative dialogue with @saulspatz . Well done.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Thanks so much; it's your kindness :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is basically correct.  By linearity of expectation, the expected number of slots with one item is $\sum{P(X_j=1)}$ where $X_j$ is the number of entries in slot $j$.

I think you have computed the probability wrong though.  You neglected to multiply by the probability that the selected item is in slot $j$.  There are $k$ ways to choose the item that will go in slot $j$.  For each such item, the probability that it is slot $j$ is $1/n$ and the probability that the remaining $n-1$ items are in slots other than n is $\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{k-1}$ as you said.  Thus $$P(X_j=1)=\frac{k}{n}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{k-1}$$

Now we have to sum over all the slots, so we multiply by $n$ and the final answer is $$k\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{k-1}$$

Is this what the book gets?

Comment: +1) Yes It is the correct answer. But may you elaborate on the reason why we should divide by $n$ in computing $P(X_j=1)$?.

Comment: @AbduMagdy Done.  Is it clear now?

Comment: $P(X_j=1)$ is a binomial distribution calculation with parameters $k$ and $\frac1n$ so can be written as ${k \choose 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^1\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{k-1}$

Comment: @Henry I think you mean $X_j$ is binomial.  Good point, though.

Comment: @saulspatz - I do not think we disagree.  $X_j$ has a binomial distribution so $P(X_j=1)$ can be calculated using the probability mass function

Comment: @Henry Absolutely.  I was just talking about the wording, not the math.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes It is clear now. Thanks so much :)